# Redux-form Field-Level Validation & error translation with React-intl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-intl

With redux-form, I try to use Field-Level Validation with i18n. I'm using react-intl (https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl), so I tried this:

```
<Field name="Label" component={renderField} validate={[required(this.props.intl)]}
```

With validation function :

```
const required = (intl) => (value) => {return value ? undefined : intl.formatMessage({id:"Required"})};
```

The issue : When I have an error in my field Label, if I change language, the state of my field is lost and my error message disappear.

I think that the value of validate props should not change between renders as it causes the field to be re-registered. What is the solution ?

How can I integrate correctly react-intl for validation messages in Field-Level Validation? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cann't use validation function wrapped into another function, every time the form is rendered it will construct a new function, which will cause field to rerender  (because `this.props.validate !== nextProps.validate`).

But you can create `Field` render component and pass localized validation message as props to it. Here is example:

```
<form>
    <Field
        name='Label'
        component={RenderField} //here you pass field render component
        validate={required}
        validationMessage={this.props.intl.formatMessage({id: 'Required'})}
    />
    {/*rest of the form*/}
</form>
```

RenderField component:

```
const RenderField = (props) => {
    const {validationMessage, meta: {touched, error}} = props;

    return <div>
        <input
            {...props}
        />
        {touched &&
        (error &&
            <div className='error'>
                {validationMessage}
            </div>)}
    </div>;
};

export default RenderField;
```

Or, if you need to have different validation messages depends on validation errors, you can create specific validation functions that will return `formatMessageId` and pass `intl` to `RenderField`:

```
const RenderField = (props) => {
    const {intl, meta: {touched, error}} = props;

    return <div>
        <input
            {...props}
        />
        {touched &&
        (error &&
            <div className='error'>
                {intl.formatMessage(error)}
            </div>)}
    </div>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, very good solution (the last with messages depending of validations errors)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Igor it is a good approach to accomplish your goal.
[React intl](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x#new-useintl-hook-as-an-alternative-of-injectintl-hoc) has a new way to inject intl in a basic way and by injecting you don't need to pass intl in your `RenderField`:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Form.Row >
        <Field name="shortName" component={RenderField}
            label={intl.formatMessage({ id: "component.userShippingAddress.shortNameLabel" })}
            placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: "component.userShippingAddress.shortNamePlaceholder" })}
            >
        </Field>
    </Form.Row>
    {/*rest of the form*/}
</Form>
```

RenderField:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { injectIntl } from "react-intl"

const RenderField = injectIntl(({intl, ...props}) => {
    const {input, label, placeholder, type, meta: {touched, error}} = props;
    const hasError = touched && error 
    return (
        <Form.Group controlId={input.name} >
            <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control isInvalid={hasError}
                {...input}
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : label}
            >
            </Form.Control>
            {hasError && <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">{intl ? intl.formatMessage({id: error}) : error}</Form.Control.Feedback>}
        </Form.Group>

    );
});
export default RenderField;
```

And you can render your custom error in your validate just passing your id from intl:

```
export const validate = formValues => {
    
    const errors = {};
  
    if (!formValues.shortName) {
      errors.shortName = 'component.userShippingAddress.shortNameNotEmpty';
    }
  
    return errors;
  };
```